# How to take a instagram user and find the count of followers it has?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, instagram

Ive tried searching online but cant seem to find anything. How would I pass in a username for a Instagram account and be able to retrieve its total followers count in Python.

In my current code which I found which should work, however I am getting this error:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'attrs'

current code

```
import instaloader
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

L = instaloader.Instaloader()
URL = "https://www.instagram.com/{}/"

def get_followers():

    # Login
    username = input("Enter your username: ")
    password = input("Enter your password: ")
    
    L.login(username, password)
    
    # Obtain profile metadata
    profile = instaloader.Profile.from_username(L.context, username)

    follow_list = []
    
    # Loop through each follower and add to list
    for followee in profile.get_followers():
        follow_list.append(followee.username)
    
    return follow_list

def parse_data(x):
    
    data = {}
    
    # Split up the data
    x = x.split("-")[0]
    x = x.split("-")
    
    # Make new key values for each attribute
    data["Followers"] = x[0]
    data["Following"] = x[2]
    data["Posts"] = x[4]
    
    return data
    

def scrape_data(username):
    
    r = requests.get(URL.format(username))
    s = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
    meta = s.find("meta", property="og : description")
    
    return parse_data(meta.attrs['content'])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    list_of_followers = get_followers()
    
    result = {}
    
    for follower in list_of_followers:
        follower_data = scrape_data(follower)
        
        # Add follower name + there followers to dictionary
        result[follower] = follower["Followers"]
        
    result = dict(sorted(result.items(), key=lambda item: item[1]))
    
    n_input = int(input("How many of your top followers do you want to see?: "))
    n_items = list(result)[:n_input]
    
    print(n_items)
```

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/products/instagram/apis/

Comment: This doesn't help me, where do i go to find how to get followers from a username?

Comment: This is saying that `s.find("meta", property="og : description")` is returning None. You can tell because that gets assigned to meta, and meta.attrs is the line where the error is. Can you print out `r.text`? I have a feeling it may not include the data you're hoping for

Comment: @Kaia I think i have a feeling its cause I've accessed the site to many times today? and been temporarily blocked, could this be the case?

Comment: It could be. It could also be you're looking at the wrong URL, or not sending the right credentials along with the request. Printing out the text and the status code of the request is the way to find out.

Comment: @Kaia are you able to try the same script please, see if it works for you? and try a URL you think might work, thanks alot

Comment: I don't have an instagram unfortunately. In `scrape_data` what are `r.status_code` and `r.text`?

Comment: @Kaia r.text is giving me the full HTML code, but I have noticed it says this in the title tag : <title> Page Not Found &bull; Instagram </title>, and the status code shows 429

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/429 Looks like your hunch was correct

Comment: @Kaia oh so thats why its showing page not found I guess, thanks for the help. I assume best bet is just to wait it out?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you aren't getting any information from the webpage, so r is empty, then s is empty, then meta is also empty, meaning it is a none type, so then trying to find the attribute attrs of meta doesn't make sense because a nonetype doesn't have any attributes.

Comment: Could this be because i have tryed to access multiple times today, and maybe been blocked temporarily?

Answer (score 0):

i have made an instaloader to make this all with kivymd which is cross platfrom:

you can find the repo here:

https://github.com/T246-Edu/instgram_loader_with_username.git

Comment: So how are you actually getting the amount of followers a user has?

Comment: using functions in the library

Comment: I tried your method but its only good for searching one person at a time, it doesn'tt work when scraping hundreds of followers

Comment: yoy can use the library to work with tons of users by using csv file and read the user name from this file in a loop